# Obsidian block command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m looking for a command that will allow me to spawn an obsidian block under a command block which the obsidian block will slowly spread to adjacent blocks. If possible, I would like for the obsidian to kill you when touched. I’ve looked everywhere for this, but I can’t find anything.

I´m using version 1.11.4 (bedrock edition) or 1.14.3 (java edition). yes i use both now.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you expect it to look like? What are you going to use it for? This will likely require more than one command as well.

Comment: I want it to just look like a “spreading” or “infecting” kind of thing from block to block and it consumes the world slowly

Comment: So it should not spread to blocks that are not air? This is likely going to become very laggy after a while. Is your map story based? Maybe you can just add some obsidian blocks at certain points in the story. The part that kills players would be a relatively simple partial solutions. Your project seems to be relatively big

Comment: How slowly should it spread?

Comment: I think I actually found a fairly simple solution, I need to test it and then I will post an answer

Comment: Thx and probably 1 all around every second

Comment: My solution would be quite a lot slower, or very laggy. It looks like you can do it with 6 command blocks and one scoreboard objective (I´m still testing it and working on it though).

Comment: It’s fine if it’s slow

Comment: Oh, you used the bedtock edition... I do not think I can make it work there either, but I can try and I know the commands better than for old java versions.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is for the java version, a recent edit added the information that it is about the bedrock edition**

Stand where you want to place a tower of command blocks and run these commands one after the other without moving away from where you are standing until you executed all 7 commands, this will slowly build a tower of command blocks one block north of your position:

```
/scoreboard objectives add hitByObsidian dummy
/setblock ~ ~ ~-1 minecraft:repeating_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{Command:"/execute as @e[tag=Spread] run data modify entity @s Pos[0] set from entity @e[limit=1,sort=random] Pos[0]"}
/setblock ~ ~1 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"/execute as @e[tag=Spread] run data modify entity @s Pos[1] set from entity @e[limit=1,sort=random] Pos[1]"}
/setblock ~ ~2 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"/execute as @e[tag=Spread] run data modify entity @s Pos[2] set from entity @e[limit=1,sort=random] Pos[2]"}
/setblock ~ ~3 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"execute as @e at @s store success score @s hitByObsidian run fill ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~1 ~1 ~1 air replace minecraft:obsidian"}
/setblock ~ ~4 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"kill @e[scores={hitByObsidian=1},tag=!Spread]"}
/setblock ~ ~5 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"execute at @e[tag=Spread,scores={hitByObsidian=1}] run fill ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~1 ~1 ~1 minecraft:obsidian replace air"}
```

The first command creates a scoreboard objective and the other 6 create a command block each.

The first command block will teleport every entity with the tag `Spread` to the same x position as a random entity
The second command block will teleport every entity with the tag `Spread` to the same y position as a random entity
The third command block will teleport every entity with the tag `Spread` to the same z position as a random entity

The fourth command block will remove all obsidian that is close to any entity and store a scoreboard value for any entity that removed obsidian (This is used to detect what entities should be killed. It also makes it possible to remove some of the infection by throwing things at it)

The fifth command block kills every entity that removed obsidian due to the fourth command block, unless they have a `Spread`-tag

The sixth command block places obsidian close to any entity with a `Spread`-tag that removed obsidian due to the fourth command block

This is mostly chance based, so it will make the obsidian spread slowly, you can speed it up by using more entities with `Spread`-tags.
I recommend you to use this command to spawn small, invulnerable, and invisible armor stands with a `Spread`-tag:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity: 1b,Invulnerable: 1b, Tags: ["Spread"],Small: 1b}
```

*Note: Once you are done with all this you need to either power the blue command block with a lever, or set it to "always active"*

*Note 2: Adding a `Spread`-tag to a player should result in interesting behaviour if that player walks close to obsidian. The player will not get teleported randomly and the obsidian won´t kill the player, though the player will likely suffocate anyway. I have not tested this yet.*

Comment: This is not required, but I recommend to run this command to prevent the command blocks from spamming chat: `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`

Comment: You can use this command `/setblock ~ ~5 ~-1 minecraft:chain_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{auto:1b,Command:"execute at @e[tag=Spread,scores={hitByObsidian=1}] run fill ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~1 ~1 ~1 minecraft:obsidian"}` instead of the last one to make this more dangerous, if you use this command instead, then the obsidian will spread through walls and everything, it will also spread under water. With the original command it was only able to spread through air blocks.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I tested it with about 25 armor stands, which lead to a speed that I consider to be good.

Comment: The commands are wrong... it says syntax error? So I guess not...

Comment: The scoreboard is good but I can’t get the next

Comment: What version of minecraft are you in?

Comment: I think 1.11.4?

Comment: Those commands are for 1.13+, I use 1.14.2. I have tested all of them and they work in 1.14.2. I´m not sure how to convert them to 1.11.4, but I can try

Comment: @Whamboy Ok, sorry, but I don´t know much about commands in earllier versions, the syntax has changed a lot, the support you get by the game itself and the functionality of the commands themselves has improoved, I can probably figure this out for 1.11.2 (there doesn´t seem to be a 1.11.4), but it will take too long, I may look at it if I have some time to spare some time though.

Comment: Ok i understand

Comment: @Mr.Bear This is for Bedrock Edition, so these commands won't work.

Comment: @cherryblossom I did not know that it was for the bedrock edition until I saw the edit from a few hours ago

Comment: @Mr.Bear Ok. I just saw the question, sorry.

Comment: @cherryblossom I edited the answer now to prevent future confusion

Comment: im curr5ently working on switching to java... dont go to the trouble to switch the commands to bedrock